# Double integral of an rotated and translated ellipse

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to solve this double integral, but can't find the especific change of coordinates. The region is an ellipse with rotation and translation of axis, I think that I need to find out the angle of rotation and the translation of each axis, and then use the classic coordinate change $x=r.cos(\theta)$, $y=r.sin(\theta)$. How can I find out the angle and the translation?

$$\int\int_A dxdy$$

where $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,,\,(2x+3y+1)^2+(2x+4y)^2=14\}$.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the transformation $u = 2x + 3y + 1$ and $v = 2x + 4y$.  The region $A$ transforms to the circle $u^2 + v^2 = 14$. Write $(u,v) = T(x,y)$ so that the change-of-variable theorem gives you $$ \iint_{T(A)} \, du dv = \iint_A |JT(x,y)| \, dx dy.$$
The Jacobian of the transformation is 
$$ JT = \begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 4 \end{vmatrix} = 2$$ so that
$$ 14 = \iint_{T(A)} \, du dv = \iint_A |JT(x,y)| \, dx dy = 2 \iint_A \, dxdy.$$